# Differentiation of determinant. Is $\frac{d}{ds} L = LW$ implies $\frac{d}{ds} \det(L) = \det(L) tr(W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

For a matrix $L$ and $W$,

1. Is $\frac{d}{ds} L = LW$ implies $\frac{d}{ds} \det(L) = \det(L) tr(W)$?
2. Is $\frac{d}{ds} \det(L) = \det(\frac{d}{ds}L)$ true?  ( I guess not)

Comment: 1. is true and 2; is (very) false...

Comment: @loup blacn, Can you prove or give me hint for the reason why 1 is true?

Comment: Item 2 is false. Here is a counter-example. Let $L(s) =s I$ for all $s$, then $\det(L(s)) = s^n $, and  $ \frac{d}{ds} \det(L) = n s^{n-1}$. On the other hand,$ \frac{d}{ds} L   = I $ and $\det(\frac{d}{ds}L)= \det(I)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\det(L))'=tr(L'adj(L))=tr(LWadj(L))=tr(adj(L)LW)=\det(L)tr(W)$.

Comment: Nice solution. In fact, you could have written it even in a shorter form: $(\det(L))'=tr(adj(L)L')=tr(adj(L)LW)=\det(L)tr(W)$.

Comment: @ Ramiro . Yes you are right.

Comment: @loup blacn, I don't understand the first statement. How can i write $(\det(L))' = tr(L'adj(L))$?

Comment: See in wikipedia, the item "Jacobi's formula".

Comment: @loupblanc Thanks!